# MIPS invert - why are the 2 operands always inverted first thing?

Tags: mips

I'm learning about MIPS 32 bit.

1. I understand that CMOS technology uses NAND and NOR for the AND and OR commands, but still, I don't understand why is the inverter at the begining. Another thing is that part that has a 1 on it (in the picture right before the inverter or as part of it) - what's its job? why are there 0 and 1 on the bitinvert?

I know how an inverter is implemented in CMOS, are we talking about that inverter here?

2. What do the 0,1 and 2 in the ALUMUX mean? Does the ALUMUX decide which of the results gets passed forward according to the current instructions?

Thanks a lot!

[image: MIPS ALU]

Comment: Those trapezoids are **muxes**, they select one input depending on the control signal depicted by the arrow. This pretty much explains all your questions.

Comment: The invert is a mux that controls whether or not you want to subtract the bits... Also don't worry about the analog aspect of CMOS for an ALU, it'll give you a headache lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't understand why is the inverter at the begining.

That is useful for subtraction. You can calculate A-B by calculating A+(~B)+1 - i.e. invert B, and turn on the carry input to add 1.

> Another thing is that part that has a 1 on it (in the picture right before the inverter or as part of it) - what's its job?

That is an unconventional symbol for an inverter, I think. The box with a "1" is a buffer (it doesn't change the signal) and the dot on the output inverts it.

> why are there 0 and 1 on the bitinvert?

Those are muxes (short for multiplexers). If Ainvert is 0, then the A1 signal is passed to the output. If Ainvert is 1, then the inverted A1 signal is passed to the output.

> What do the 0,1 and 2 in the ALUMUX mean? Does the ALUMUX decide which of the results gets passed forward according to the current instructions?

Same thing as the Ainvert and Binvert muxes, but now there are 3 choices instead of just 2. Yes it does.

Comment: "Invert at the beginning" (depending on the source of the data : e.g. if it's a pipeline register) may also be free, given that registers generally have both Q and notQ outputs. So there may not physically be an inverter there.